# TastyPie - filtering on related resources

Tags: django, tastypie

Let's say I have two TastyPie resources:

```
class LicenseResource(ModelResource):
    ...

class UserResource(ModelResource):

    license = fields.ForeignKey(LicenseResource, 'license', full=False, null=True, blank=True)
    filtering = { "license": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS }
    ...
```

Assume every user is assigned to a single license. Let's say a user (assigned to license with id=1) makes the following request to retrieve all users on License #2:

```
/accounts/api/v1/user/?license__id=2
```

This user isn't assigned to this license, so they shouldn't be able to perform this query.

How can I apply filtering to restrict users from only filtering on the license that they are assigned to? I've been reading the documentation but I'm having a hard time getting my head around how to handle this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
class LicenseResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        filtering = {'id': ALL}
        ...

class UserResource(ModelResource):

    license = fields.ForeignKey(LicenseResource, 'license', full=False, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        filtering = { "license": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS }
        ...
```